# Vlookup in Googleappscripting

Tags: google-apps-script, vlookup, gs-vlookup

I have this code developed but I may be doing something wrong with my vlookup formula. I am trying to create a report that allows me to lookup a primary key in my source spreadsheet. Once it finds the primary key in my source spreadsheet, I want it to spit a particular metric in my target spreadsheet. My code works but when it runs it gives me "what is displayed in the picture"[image]

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Reporting')
 .addItem('Run Report', 'runReport') 
 .addToUi()
}

function runReport() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Target 
  Spreadsheet").getRange("A1");
  generateReport();
}

function generateReport(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Target Spreadsheet");
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source Spreadsheet");
  var cell = ss.getRange("A1");
  var cello = ss.getRange("B1");
  var vlookup = "=VLOOKUP(cell,sh!A:C,2,0)";
  cello.setFormula(vlookup);

}
```

Comment: I guess my picture did not return anything, but when the script is ran, it just gives me an error in the cell B1 of #NAME

Comment: Vlookup requires strings. Search_key must be a string. `cell` is a range object(a JavaScript object), so is `sh`. They cannot be used like that.

Comment: Something like this might work `var vlookup = Utilities.formatString('=VLOOKUP(\'%s\',\'%s!A:C\',2,0)',cell.getA1Notation(),ts.getName());`.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the response. It is indeed very helpful. The only thing I am struggling with is actually the second part of the argument. The formula looks up the value in the same spreadsheet rather than looking up the value in the my sh spreadsheet. I am thinking that I may need to add more arguments after ss.getName and not ts.getName for the member number to look up the value in the source spreadsheet. I am also not sure if that is the right approach.